Despite tides the Moon, as far as I know, doesn't slow down. Where does the energy come from?
Hy, I don't have anything to do with physics, so please forgive me if I explain my question in a weird way ;)
As the Moon rotates around the earth it is creating tides and waves on the earth. IE it's releasing energy on Earth through it's gravitational pull.
But the Moon, as far as I know, doesn't slow down. Where does the energy come from? Is it slowly using up it's kinetic energy?

There are three places for the rotational motion to store energy and angular momentum. The Earth rotates about the North-South axis, and the Moon also has its own. The Moon and the Earth also orbit about a common centre that is inside the Earth. These are slowing down, and that energy is what is used to make tidal waves. Those tidal waves then later turn into heat energy.

Related: Why doesn't the Moon fall onto the Earth?, Why does the Moon drift away from Earth? and links therein.

@PM2Ring I was hoping that it would be closed as duplicate and later system auto-deleted. Sadly, now we have someone else giving an answer to this.

@naturallyInconsistent I deleted my answer.

@paulina your answer was ok, dont be hard on yourself
